# How can I verify inside a Set Variable (Mule 4) if a parameter exists without having a Value Selector error?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, dataweave, mule-esb

I am using Mule 4 and I have a Value Error Selector when the payload is a string instead of having the following structure:

```
{"status": 0, "content": {"status": "201",...........
```

I am using a set variable in Mule 4 giving this value:

```
<set-variable value="#[if (payload.content? and payload.content.status? and payload.content.status &gt;= 200) payload.content.status else 500]" doc:name="Set Status" doc:id="e9ce4fd1-9664-4401-b9a2-e47913b689af" variableName="httpStatus"/>
```

the condition I am using is :

```
if (payload.content? and payload.content.status? and payload.content.status >= 200) payload.content.status else 500
```

but sometimes the server can answer a string like 'Non Authorized', then payload.content doesn't exist, is just a string.

Set Variable is giving me this error when the payload is an string

```
"\"You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: \n 1: Binary (\"Richiesta Non Autorizzata\" as Binary {encoding: \"UTF-8\", mediaType: \"text/ht...)\n 2: Name (\"content\")\n\nBut it expects one of these combinations:\n (Array, Name)\n (Array, String)\n (Date, Name)\n (DateTime, Name)\n (LocalDateTime, Name)\n (LocalTime, Name)\n (Object, Name)\n (Object, String)\n (Period, Name)\n (Time, Name)\n\n1| if (payload.content? and payload.content.status? and payload.content.status >= 200) payload.content.status else 500\n ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\nTrace:\n at main (line: 1, column: 5)\" evaluating expression: \"if (payload.content? and payload.content.status? and payload.content.status >= 200) payload.content.status else 500\".",
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `payload.content.status default {}` or you can default it to a string or some other value that you can compare later and work with.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is instead of checking if the field exists check if the value is Object then you can make sure `.status` is going to work

```
if (payload.content is Object and payload.content.status? and payload.content.status >= 200) 
    payload.content.status 
else 500
```